# Number only script doesn't work in firefox 17

Tags: javascript

Hi I have below code in a Javascript. This does not work
(You can type in letters) on Firefox 17 and works fine with other browsers. Can some one tell me a workaround? Thank you for looking.

```
function onlyNumbers(evt)
{
var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

return true;

}
```

EDIT:

```
<input name="outletno" type="text" id="outletno" size="15" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers()" value="<?= htmlentities ($values['outletno']) ?>"></td>
```

Comment: What event are you using? When you check in the debugger, what are the various values you see for "charCode" in Firefox vs. other browsers?

Comment: Please specify what "does not work" means

Comment: Also the test to see if the character code is greater than 31 is incorrect. It'll mean that all control characters will be accepted as digits.

Answer (score 3):

You're not passing the event parameter to your function.

```
<input name="outletno" type="text" id="outletno" size="15" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event)" value="<?= htmlentities ($values['outletno']) ?>"></td>
```

Firefox doesn't have a global "event" symbol. Your function expects a parameter, but you weren't passing it.

You can think of the browser's handling of "onfoo" element attributes as if it constructs a function for you with the `Function` constructor, as follows:

```
element.onfoo = new Function(attributeValue, "event");
```

(That's not *really* what happens, but it's effectively like that.)  It means that the code in the attribute value can expect that there's a parameter called "event" available, and so that's what you'll pass to your function.

Your code works in IE, Chrome, and Safari because those browsers *do* keep the "event" value around as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad way to check for numbers only. charCode are far from being anything but cross-browser. Here is an article explaining most differences (if not all) of the keyboard events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Overall, it's telling you to avoid using them as much as possible.

Here is a correct way (using onkeyup, because onkeypress doesn't have the updated value):

```
document.getElementById('outletno').onkeyup = function() {
    // If the value isn't a number, take off the last character
    if (!/\d+/.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
    }
};
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uFRwZ/

Comment: The value won't be updated by a "keypress" event, I don't think.

Comment: This only tests whether there is a numeral in the value.  Replacing `/\d+/` with `/^\d+$/` will restrict the value to numerals.

Comment: @MikeSamuel but how would you insert anything but a numeral? :)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, `/\d+/.test("1")` and `/\d+/.test("1a")` are both true, so first type '1', then 'a', and you will have a value with a numeral that is not all numerals even though at every stage its value matched `/\d+/`.